# BAPI_ALM_ORDER_MAINTAIN Error IW:430 - Start date may not fall after end date

Tags: abap

I'm calling the `BAPI_ALM_ORDER_MAINTAIN` function module like so to create a work order:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_ALM_ORDER_MAINTAIN'
    TABLES
      it_methods      = lt_methods
      it_header       = lt_header
      it_header_up    = lt_header_up
      it_operation    = lt_operation
      it_operation_up = lt_operation_up
      it_srule        = lt_srule
      it_srule_up     = lt_srule_up
      return          = lt_return
      extension_in    = lt_extension_in.
```

In my `lt_header` table, I have the following information:

[image: lt_header dates]

It's proven problematic for me to leave the `finish_date` initial. When I make the function module call, the error `430` from the `IW` message class is returned: `Start date may not fall after end date`. If I enter a valid finish date, the work order is created successfully.

I'm able to create a work order manually in IW31 without entering a `finish_date`.

Here is the configuration for this particular plant and order type (which I've removed from the photo):

[image: Configuration]

Is there a way to submit this BAPI without specifying a finish date?

Comment: What are the contents of `lt_header_up`?

Comment: @vwegert - ooo, this is interesting. Since I'm only performing a create, I was not filling this in, as I was under the impression that I only set that under a change. I added a record with an `X` for `start_date` and `finish_date`, and this let me create my work order. If you would like to formally answer that, I'll accept your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that you flag the start date with `X` in `it_header_up`, but leave the finish date unflagged - this way the missing finish date should not cause issues.

Comment: Just a side note - contrary to how I thought it would be, if I leave `finish_date` initial (`00000000`), I actually do need to leave a flag in the update table for it to work. If I don't flag it to update, it gives me the same error.